# Find code which is responsible for reducing opacity of Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to reduce the opacity of image in [site](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/drop-it-like-its-hot.html) and I did it by decreasing opacity value in below code. But when I tried to search code: `opacity: 0.3`, I didn't get that code anywhere in the site files. I tried `fgrep -r "opacity : 0.3"`, and still I didn't find it. Opacity code is coming from 3rd party plugin we are using.

Is there any way to override that opacity of the image [ Means Image which is displaying outside the Mug in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/drop-it-like-its-hot.html)  by adding new class?

[image]

Image :

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan sorry, i will update with code and remove the image......

Answer (score 0):

Overriding style can be done with

```
style="opacity:1"
```

at the element.

Or create a new class in your css:

```
.aitraph>svg>image{
  opacity:1 !important;
}
```

and give your element this ccs class.

Comment: Thanks, but issue is i am not getting code of <image> tag also..... than only i can add the new css class for <image> tag right ?

Comment: Or you can specify image by parent elements e.g. `#parent1>.parent2 image`.

Comment: can you please check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/drop-it-like-its-hot.html) and upload image and try inspect element for `image part out of mug` as i posted in question....

Comment: I cannot see the image however this should do the trick `.aitraph>svg>image{opacity:1 !important;}`

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i tried your code, now opacity is changing for the complete Image that we uploaded . but i want to change opacity only for the `part of image` that is displaying outside of mug....  please check https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOJo3.png

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could override it is by using the !important tag  after you CSS property in your stylsheet. If you do not use the important then than the inline style will always take precedent to any style sheets.

Example:

```
.whateverClass {
 color: 000 !important;
}
```

Edit: Now knowing that you do not have the ability to add a class to the element, you can use css child selectors as outlined below as I can see an ID on the svg parent object that you could target:

https://jsfiddle.net/sLtgsqyk/

html example:

```
<div id="test">
 <svg width="391" height="391" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <image href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUQYl.png" x="0" y="0" height="1276" width="2000"/>
 </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#test > svg > image
 {
   height: 1000px !important;
   width: 1500px !important;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but issue is i am not getting code of <image> tag also..... than only i can add the new css class for <image> tag right ?

Comment: So are you saying the image itself is generated by some third party so you are unable to add a class to it?

Comment: thats right,  please check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/drop-it-like-its-hot.html) and upload image and try inspect element for `image part out of mug` as i posted in question....

Comment: I'm on my phone right now so can't really. Here is what you could do though. Just glancing at your HTML screen shot, the parent div Of the image's parent has a class defined. You can define CSS for styles based upon that. Here is a link that shows a basic example https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp

Comment: You can also do this through jquery as well with the .addClass() function.

Comment: You would either want to load it in the document.ready method https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ or in a included script near the bottom of the page. If not then the add class might execute before the dom element is created so it will not work. That is of course assuming that your third party images are not being generated by an Ajax call after page load itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148062/discussion-between-stackoverflow-user-and-travis-acton).

Answer (score -1):

You can add new class to image (e.g. `.opacity_img`) and set style  `opacity:0.3!important`

Don't like `!important` but it can help you

Comment: Thanks, but issue is i am not getting code of <image> tag also..... than only i can add the new css class for <image> tag right ?

Comment: Can you detect your image by css selectors? It'll solved the problem

Comment: can you please check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/drop-it-like-its-hot.html) and upload image and try inspect element for image part out of mug as i posted in question....

Comment: hi, did you checked link ?

Comment: yes, but i can't use jquery on devtools to get the solution

Comment: it means you have to try do it on real project not chrome devtools

Comment: ah yes, but actually what i want to know is we need to use `jquery` only to get solution right, we cant achieve by `css` ?

Comment: i use jq only for convenience in selectors, u can try css of course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148192/discussion-between-stackoverflow-user-and-dsb).